# Why is there no torque in electric motors when the Iq current is zero and Id current is not zero?

Tags: coil, magnet, pmsm, ac-motor, rotor

Random vector position of stator current ( Id + Iq = Is ):

[image: Random current vector position in red]

Now I draw the stator current/flux vector as shown below where “Iq = 0” and “Id ≠ 0”:

[image: current vector Is lies on d-axis]

From lecture I’ve learned that the south pole of the rotor (permanent magnet) lies on the d-axis.
In this case it would look like below:

[image: Rotor magnet lies on d-axis]

I’ve also learned from lecture that the direction of the stator current depends on the stator coils which are currently energized.

[image: Stator current Is]

So if I add all those things together, I would expect a picture like below:

[image: Rotor magnet supposed to turn?]

in this case, the two outer magnets would repel the rotor magnet so that the rotor magnet would rotate by 180°, wouldn't they?

So the torque would not be zero.

Where is my mistake?

I’m a mechanical engineer.

Comment: Consider: in which direction would they repel it?